# Let C be the 12-cycle listed below, for which positive intergers i is C$^i$ also a 12 cycle

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have a proof of the following result. It would be appreciated if someone could review my works. Thanks!

> Let C be the 12-cycle in the context of the symmetric group, S$_n$. Define C as (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12). For which positive integers i is C$^i$ also a 12-cycle.

Claim: The set A = {i | lcm(i,12) = 12i } is the set of i such that C$^i$ is also a 12-cycle.

Proof:

Any cycle construction begins with (x,....) for some 1 $\le$ x $\le$ 12. All other x values we are not concerned with since C(x) = x by definition of the cycle decomposition. In order for the cycle to have 12 values before a right parenthesis, there must be 11 values that do not map to the number 1.

Note that C$^i$(x) = (x + i) modulo 12, where the residue class $\bar{0}$ = 12.   So then for any fixed i we have the following sequence:

(1, 1 + i, (1+i) + i, 1 + 3i, 1 + 4i, ... )

and we have for y $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ that $$1 + yi = 1 $$

or equivalently when

$$yi = 0 $$

But yi = 0 implies that yi = 12$n$ for some $n$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ since each value in our cycle is modulo 12 where $\bar{0}$ = 12. Then since any cycle can be permuted to the form:

$$ (1, 1 + i, 1 + 2i, 1 + 3i, ... ) $$

we only care about cycles that have the first 12 terms such that yi is not a multiple of 12. Hence 1i, 2i, 3i, ... 11i are not multiples of 12 or else that spot would require a right parenthesis since then 1 + yi = 1. In this case 0i is taken as not a multiple of 12.

So if the lcm(i,12) = 12i then no value of 1i,2i,3i, ..., 11i could have ended the cycle before 12 terms are listed.

So our set of i values such that  C$^i$ also a 12-cycle is the set A = {i | lcm(i,12) = 12i }.

Comment: I think your argument is fine! The condition $\operatorname{lcm}(i,12)=12i$ may also be written as $\gcd(i,12)=1$, which may be a little more suggestive (in general $\gcd(a,b)\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)=ab$).

Comment: More generally, if $G$ is a group and $g \in G$ has order $n$, then $g^i$ has order $n/\gcd(n,i)$.